# Layouts contents are not displaying proper format in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

[![want to display occupy the luminary data completely and controller data completely but it is displaying like this]
Hi in the below code contains two tabs named as luminary and controllers.

Under that luminary displaying different layouts .
below are the contents for luminary:
1.All luminaries
2.luminaries on
3.luminaries off
4.luminaries not working

under the controllers contents below data:
1.POE controllers
2.LORA controllers

but my layout are displaying like this

Home.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/realmsbg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/luminary_controll"
        android:background="@color/color_white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/luminary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorNatural"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Luminary"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:id="@+id/all_luminary">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/color_white">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                        android:tint="@color/colorNatural"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ALL LUMINARIES"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorNatural"
                        android:id="@+id/luminarie"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/color_green">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                        android:tint="@color/color_white"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="LUMINARIES ON"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                        android:id="@+id/sensors"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:background="@color/color_red"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                        android:tint="@color/color_white"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="LUMINARIES OFF"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                        android:id="@+id/drivers"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/color_gray">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                        android:tint="@color/color_white"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="LUMINARIES NOT"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                            android:id="@+id/lum_not"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="270dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="WORKING"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/color_white"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/controller"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Controller"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/all_controllers"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/color_white"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                        android:tint="@color/colorNatural"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Lora Controller"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorNatural"
                        android:id="@+id/lora_control"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/color_green">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bulb"
                        android:tint="@color/color_white"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="POE Controller"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                        android:id="@+id/poe_control"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Home.java:

```
    private void clickListener() {


        luminary.setOnTouchListener (new View.OnTouchListener ( ) {
            @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mluminarySelected=true;
                control.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext (), R.color.color_white));
                luminary.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext (), R.color.colorNatural));
                luminary.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext (), R.color.color_white));
                control.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext (), R.color.colorNatural));

                all_luminary.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                all_controllers.setVisibility (INVISIBLE);
                return false;
            }
        });

        control.setOnTouchListener (new View.OnTouchListener ( ) {
            @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mluminarySelected=false;
                control.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext (), R.color.colorNatural));
                luminary.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext (), R.color.color_white));
                luminary.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext (), R.color.colorNatural));
                control.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext (), R.color.color_white));
                all_controllers.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                all_luminary.setVisibility (INVISIBLE);
                return false;
            }
        });



    }

    private void init() {

        //luminary_controllers=(LinearLayout)findViewById (R.id.lu)
        luminary=(TextView)findViewById (R.id.luminary);
        control=(TextView)findViewById (R.id.controller);
        all_luminary=(LinearLayout)findViewById (R.id.all_luminary);
        all_controllers=(LinearLayout)findViewById (R.id.all_controllers);
        all_controllers.setVisibility (INVISIBLE);
 }
```

Comment: Can you add output screenshot ?

Comment: @MehulSolanki please check it out

Comment: show your fragment class

Comment: @notTdar not using fragment class

Comment: Show the onCreate() of your activity, have you called clickListener() in there?

Comment: @VedprakashWagh yes. without clickListner how am getting the data.content is not displaying in proper formast

Comment: @VedprakashWagh my java code was correct.only xml layout having some issues

Comment: Can you add code for your Home.java? because your layout looks fine on my end

Comment: I already added